# How can I bundle a local dependency into jar build by gradle?

Tags: gradle

The problem is that I have three sibling projects. Only two are important here lets call them shared and client. client depends on shared and since I've done that all locally I define that dependency like compile project(':shared') in the build.gradle for the client project. Now I want to publish the client with help of the maven-publish plugin. When I do that every project that depends on the client fails because it can't find the shared project anywhere.

Now that makes complete sense at it is not published anywhere it's just there when building the client. I now want the artifact of the client project to include all the classes by the shared project. Also I want the client artifact to no longer say it depends on the shared project but it should now depend on everything that shared depended on.

And I've already done a ton of research, I found [this question and answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-dependencies-in-jar/19571/5) that shows how to include a specific dependency into the resulting artifact. The problem with that is that is includes all the dependencies of the shared project into the jar as well as the files of the shared project.

My questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable approach? If not what would be better?
2. How can I only put the classes of the direct dependency `shared`
   into the jar build by `client`?
3. How can I exclude `shared` but not it's dependencies from the
   artifacts the maven-publish plugin generates?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to question 2:

In the build.gradle you need to add this:

```
configurations {
    localCompile.transitive = false
    compile.extendsFrom(localCompile)
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.localCompile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Then simply define all local dependencies like `localCompile project(":kuroji-websocket-shared")`.